# How to optimize this query in ActiveRecord - latest 10 topics by friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`User` model:

```
 user_id  phone_no
 -------  --------
   1      555-0001
   2      555-0002
   .
   .
```

Every user has his/her own phone number.

`Friend` model:

```
 user_id  phone_no
 -------  --------
  user 1  555-0002
  user 1  555-0003
  user 2  555-0001
  user 2  555-0004
```

User may has many phones numbers. A phone number match is consider as a friend (one direction), e.g. owner of `555-0003` is a friend of `user 1`, not vise versa.

`Topic` model:

```
  topic_id  user_id  title
  --------  -------  -----
      1        1     Hello
      2        1     Hi
```

How to optimize the query of getting the latest 10 topics by friends of a user?

I tried something like:

```
user = User.find(2) # any user
phones = Friend.all(:conditions=>['user_id = ?',user.id],:select=>'phone_no').map {|x| x.phone_no}
friends = User.all(:conditions=>['phone_no in (?), phones]).map {|x| x.user_id}
topics = Topic.all(:conditions=>['user_id in (?), friends], :limit => 10, :order => 'updated_at DESC')
```

but worried about performance when breaking up queries. How can I optimize this ActiveRecord query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User
  has_many :topics
  has_many :friends
  has_many :friend_users, :through => :friends
  has_many :friend_topics, :through => :friend_users, :source => :topics      
end

class Friend
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :phone_no, 
                :primary_key  => :phone_no
end

class Topic
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now given a user you can get the friend topics as follows:

```
current_user.friend_topics.limit(10)
```

Make sure you add

- an unique index on the `phone_no` col in the `User` class
- an index on the `phone_no` col in the `Friend` class.

Comment: Regarding _"unique index on the phone_no col"_, what can be the side effect if I leave the `phone_no` col optional in `User` model, thus index not unique?

Comment: I think it should be fine. Make sure you add a non null constraint on the `phone_no` col in `Friend` model.