# What is ActiveRecord equivalence in the node.js world?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, activerecord

I am considering to use `node.js` tools for a upcoming project, for learning and performance purpose. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151243/how-to-optimize-this-query-in-activerecord-latest-10-topics-by-friends), some models in Rails:

```
class User
  has_many :topics
  has_many :friends
  has_many :friend_users, :through => :friends
  has_many :friend_topics, :through => :friend_users, :source => :topics      
end

class Friend
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend_user, :class_name => "User", 
      :foreign_key => :phone_no, :primary_key  => :phone_no
end

class Topic
  belongs_to :user
end
```

allows elegant query code like:

```
latest_10_topics_from_friends = current_user.friend_topics.limit(10)
```

and generates optimized SQLs. Is there something similar in `node.js` ecosystem?

Comment: Most likely mysql or postgre.

Comment: check out http://sailsjs.org

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Updated answer

Use [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize)

---

#### Old answer:

Look at the [Tower](https://github.com/viatropos/tower) project. You can define your models as follows:

```
# app/models/user.coffee
class App.User extends Tower.Model
  @belongsTo "author", type: "User"
  @belongsTo "commentable", polymorphic: true
  @has_many "topics"
  @has_many "friends"
  @has_many "friend_users", through: "friends"
  @has_many "friend_topics", through: "friends_users", source: "topics"

# app/models/friend.coffee
class App.Friend extends Tower.Model
  @belongs_to "user"
  @belongs_to "friend_user", type: "User", 
                foreign_key: "phone_no", primary_key: "phone_no"

# app/models/topic.coffee
class App.Topic extends Tower.Model
  @belongs_to "user"
```

Now you will be able to query your data as

```
current_user.friend_topics().limit(10)
```

Comment: For anyone reading this as of 2015, Tower is now unmaintained according to their documentation, no new commits for 1-2 years. Keep on looking...

Comment: Yea, Tower is totally dead. Advise updating answer.

Comment: sequelize is node's answer for an orm, but it's garbage compared to activerecord. Activerecord is simple and sequelize is verbose.

Answer (score 14):

Waterline seems to be the thing that you're looking for. It was created by the same guys behind the Sails Project.

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline

Comment: I have a simple question: is there a way of getting waterline to work without defining attributes on the model? Like it’s possible here: https://github.com/3kg4kR/active_record

Comment: Waterline doesn't support many to many relations properly, let alone "through" relations.

Comment: @morbaq Waterline actually has 100% support for many-to-many relations.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MySql, you can try Sequelize.js.
It's hard to reach the number of features that ActiveRecord offers, but nevertheless, I have been working with Sequelize and its a nice solution for Node.js

There are several other ORM solutions for other DB, you can check them here http://search.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

[mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) is probably the closest analogy though it's for a document store not a relational db like rails/active record

Comment: While mongoose may not be exactly what the OP is looking for it is a legitimate answer here. It has many of the capabilities of ActiveRecord albeit tied to MongoDB rather than an SQL database.